# Liberty OpenId Connect Error 403: AuthorizationFailed

Tags: java, openid-connect, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I am trying to access a protected servlet(`whoAmI`) which require `xyz` role.

Using keycloak as openid provider, this is my openid-connect configuration

```xml
<openidConnectClient id="RP" scope="openid" signatureAlgorithm="RS256"
    clientId="liberty" clientSecret="secret"
    discoveryEndpointUrl="https://localhost:8243/auth/realms/abc/.well-known/openid-configuration"
    userIdentityToCreateSubject="id"
    groupIdentifier="groupof"
    realmName="abc"
    />
<application type="ear" location="/opt/was-services.ear"></application>
```

This is my `web.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>abcServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ABCServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>abcServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/abc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>secure</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/abc</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description></description>
            <role-name>test</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description>test</description>
        <role-name>test</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

ear `META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_2.xsd"
                 xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                 version="1.2">

    <security-role name="test">
        <group name="gpTest"/>
    </security-role>

</application-bnd>
```

While accessing the servlet, it redirecting me to keycloak login page and after successful login redirected me back to servlet path, but giving error `Error 403: AuthorizationFailed`

`The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [test]`

Liberty accepted access-token & created session, i can see `WAS_p158005998` cookie in browser.
Somehow authorisation failing. Not sure how to map keycloak groups to liberty.

Both accessToken & idToken contain id & groupof(array) fields like below.

```json
{
  "id": "user1",
  "groupof": [
    "gpTest",
    "gpTest2"
  ]
}
```

Do I need to map any registry? or is my application binding is wrong (i tried direct group name gpTest, but no use)?

Comment: In your appliction-bnd file, I think the group element needs an access-id attribute as noted here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_authorization.html#d337475e272

Comment: @Bruce T yup you spot it, worked like a charm. make it as answer, will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `application-bnd.xml` file, I think the group element needs an `access-id` attribute as noted here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_authorization.html#d337475e272